# Heroku deployed discord bot but gives error: Cannot find module '/app/bot.js'

Tags: node.js, heroku, deployment

I've managed to create a Discord bot with open source code, put it in a Github repository, and successfully link it to Heroku. When I manually deploy the app from Heroku, it says it was successfully deployed, but when I open the app I'm shown an error page. When I run `heroku logs --tail`  in my terminal, `Error: Cannot find module '/app/bot.js'` comes up in the log. But, I don't have a file called bot.js, I only have `worker: node bot.js` in my Procfile. Here's a more lengthy bit of the log:

```
2021-02-08T06:23:42.936452+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: Starting process with command `node bot.js`
2021-02-08T06:23:43.667657+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: State changed from starting to up
2021-02-08T06:23:44.939715+00:00 app[worker.1]: node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:928
2021-02-08T06:23:44.939740+00:00 app[worker.1]: throw err;
2021-02-08T06:23:44.939740+00:00 app[worker.1]: ^
2021-02-08T06:23:44.939741+00:00 app[worker.1]: 
2021-02-08T06:23:44.939741+00:00 app[worker.1]: Error: Cannot find module '/app/bot.js'
2021-02-08T06:23:44.939755+00:00 app[worker.1]: at Function.Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:925:15)
2021-02-08T06:23:44.939760+00:00 app[worker.1]: at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:769:27)
2021-02-08T06:23:44.939761+00:00 app[worker.1]: at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:76:12)
2021-02-08T06:23:44.939761+00:00 app[worker.1]: at node:internal/main/run_main_module:17:47 {
2021-02-08T06:23:44.939762+00:00 app[worker.1]: code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
2021-02-08T06:23:44.939762+00:00 app[worker.1]: requireStack: []
2021-02-08T06:23:44.939762+00:00 app[worker.1]: }
2021-02-08T06:23:45.012747+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: Process exited with status 1
2021-02-08T06:23:45.073347+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: State changed from up to crashed
```

Things I attempted:

- Added `"engines": { "node": "15.x", "npm": "7.x" }` to package.json
- Ran `git ls-files | grep node_modules` to try to stop tracking modules, but this does not return any results. I ran the rest of the code associated with this fix anyways
- Ran `heroku config:set NODE_MODULES_CACHE=false`
- Added `worker: npm start` to Procfile
- Ran `npm install discord.js --save`

I want to try to find this `app/` directory but I don't know where that is, or even if I'm focusing on the right part of the log. I'm brand new to coding so apologies if I left out any code from a different file that's relevant, I can add anything if necessary.

Comment: Heroku git shallow clones your git repo into the folder `app/`. The error basically says there is no `bot.js` in thefolder. If there is one in your git repo root folder then the mistake  was made during build. Check your build log. https://i.imgur.com/FRiaVCe.png

Comment: @TinNguyen thanks so much for the directions, I went to my build log but wasn't able to find anything mentioning an `app/` folder. However, it does start with `Node.js app detected` at the top of the log. I don't have a bot.js file at all in any of my repo folders though, so I don't know why it would be an error to not be able to find it when it wasn't called for in the code.

Comment: Your `Procfile` references a `bot.js`, see `worker: node bot.js`. If you don't have a `bot.js` then that's the error right there. Either create a file named `bot.js` and put code there or adjust your `Procfile` to however else you are executing your project.

Comment: @TinNguyen Thank you SO much!! The open source code was calling the file `index.js`, I changed it and all mentions to `bot.js` and even though I still get an error message from Heroku the bot is live and working on discord. So I'm considering it solved. If you want to rewrite that as a direct answer to my question I can give it the green checkmark :) Thanks again!